# Laravel date range not working with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, date

Hi I have one column name as date which will hold advance payment date. I want to fetch current month date advance paid. for what i am using below code.

```
echo $startDate = date($currentYear . "-" . $currentMonth . "-1");
echo $endDate = date($currentYear . "-" . $currentMonth . "-" . $numberOfDaysInMonth);
DB::enableQueryLog();
echo $advances = UserServiceAdvancePayment::where('user_service_master_id', $userServiceMasterObject->id)
    ->whereDate('date', ">=", $startDate)
    ->whereDate('date', "<", $endDate)
    ->get();
```

Herein am getting data when am applying one date condition but when applying other it is not returning data. Also tried with between there also same issue. Any help is deeply appreciated on this

Comment: is your dates correct? I do not see any error there, how is your query generated?

Comment: select * from "user_service_advance_payments" where "user_service_master_id" = ? and date >= '2021-03-1' and date <= '2021-03-31' this is how query is created. When i dont pass date <= '2021-03-31' it returns record o 2021-03-11

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need to do correctly then it's easier to use Carbon to do it:

```
$startDate = CarbonImmutable::createFromDate($currentYear, $currentMonth, 1)
$endDate = CarbonImmutable::createFromDate($currentYear, $currentMonth, 1)->endOfMonth();
DB::enableQueryLog();
$advances = UserServiceAdvancePayment::where('user_service_master_id', $userServiceMasterObject->id)
    ->whereDate('date', ">=", $startDate)
    ->whereDate('date', "<=", $endDate)
    ->get();
```

Comment: thank you for your response but still the output is none.